# programatically copy values from one column to another in SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

i have seen some questions similar but none is exactly the same. I want to copy all columns in one row in a table to another row. This table has X columns. Can I do this programatically, if pk is just id?

so

```
table_1
id | col1 | col2 | ... | colX
1    a.     b.     ...    d
2    q.     w.     ...    r
```

I want then at the end to have:

```
id | col1 | col2 | ... | colX
1    a.     b.     ...    d
2    a.     b.     ...    d
```

How can I write this in a simple way? I can't use a temp id, because this id had a constraint that it needs to exist somewhere else before.

I'm using Springboot if that helps..

Answer (score 2):

Just specify *what goes where*:

Before:

```
SQL> select * From test order by id;

        ID COL1  COL2  COL3
---------- ----- ----- -----
         1 a     b     d
         2 q     w     r
```

Update:

```
SQL> update test a set
  2    (a.col1, a.col2, a.col3) =
  3    (select b.col1, b.col2, b.col3
  4     from test b
  5     where b.id = 1
  6    )
  7  where a.id = 2;

1 row updated.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * From test order by id;

        ID COL1  COL2  COL3
---------- ----- ----- -----
         1 a     b     d
         2 a     b     d

SQL>
```